# AmCharts4: add data dynamically

Tags: amcharts4

In my application, I have many charts. Those charts show realtime data from 1 day ago until now. I implemented an autoupdate, which periodically adds new datapoints to the chart. I use this method: `chart.addData(dataArray,removeCount)`
I also implemented a function that loads one further day in the past by pressing a button. This works fine by loading the data, and then doing:

```
chart.data.unshift(...dataArray);
chart.invalidateData();
```

but i rather want something like this:

```
chart.unshiftData(dataArray,removeCount)
```

Because if i call invalidate on a chart with 15000 datapoints, the chart freezes the browser for a moment. I do not really know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no such function so you're kind of out of luck. With that many data points, consider enabling [data grouping](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Dynamic_data_item_grouping) to improve performance if you're using a date axis.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In this case, the user just has to endure a little more wait time than when refreshing data.

I tried grouping already, but this leads to another strange behaviour: the "series.toolTipText={1} exampleText" shows only "exampleText" without the value instead of "123 exampleText" when zoomed out(zoomed in, its ok). I looked at the tutorial you linked, and it seems to work there. The only difference I spotted was that i use an array (0 is the date, 1 is the value) instead of an object with a date-value pair. Might this lead to bugs? Or did I just overlook something?

Comment: AmCharts only supports array of objects. Not sure how you got an array of arrays to work, but, that's probably not the way to go. As for tooltip placeholders, if those are meant to be values from your data, use the [special placeholder names](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Placeholder_examples) like `{valueY}`. This will map to the correct value when grouping is enabled, unlike directly named values.

Comment: So i tried to do what you suggested, I now use an array of objects. An entry looks like this `{date:1582721617,value:123}`. I changed the assignment accordingly:
 `series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
                                series.groupFields.valueY = "average";
                                series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
                                series.tooltipText = "{valueY}"`

I also set dateAxis.groupData=true. However, the value is still not showing up

Comment: I can't troubleshoot blindly at this point. Please provide a fiddle or codepen.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I actually noticed that it was just a stupid mistake of setting the toolTipText two times, so problem solved!